# Reflecting method with parameters and return type from object using conditional types

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to invoke function with reflections and keeping it's types at the same time.

It seems that `T extends OnlyFunctions<Foo>` works fine, but K does not seem to "remember" that T consists only of `AnyFunctions`.

I get error:
`Type 'T[K]' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'`

What is the way to solve this?

```
type AnyFunction = (...args: any[]) => any;

type Only<T, S> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends S ? K : never
}[keyof T];

type OnlyFunctions<T> = Pick<T, Only<T, AnyFunction>>;


interface Foo {
    a: (x1: number, x2: number) => number;
    b: (y: string) => string;
}

const foo: Foo = {
    a: (x: number, x1: number) => { return x + x1 + 1 },
    b: (y: string) => { return y + "y" },
}
const invoke = <T extends OnlyFunctions<Foo>, K extends keyof T>(
    method: K,
    ...args: Parameters<T[K]>,
): ReturnType<T[K]> => {
    return foo[method].call(foo, args)
};

invoke("a", 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing a few problems with your example code; the one directly relevant to your question is that `T` is a generic type that *extends* `OnlyFunctions<Foo>`, meaning it may well have more properties than declared in `OnlyFunctions<Foo>`, due to the way structural subtyping works in TypeScript (object types in TypeScript are *open*, not [exact](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)).  If `T extends {foo: string}` then `T` could be `{foo: string, bar: number}` or `{foo: string, baz: boolean}`.  So the compiler cannot assume that `T`'s known properties are only functions, even though `OnlyFunctions<Foo>`'s known properties are only functions.

I'd suggest removing `T` entirely since it's not doing you any good in those examples (there's nothing for it to be inferred from), and replace it with `OnlyFunctions<Foo>`.  You can keep `K`.

After that, there are still a few issues... invalid trailing comma, use of `call` instead of [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) (or maybe use of `args` instead of `...args`, depending on how you look at it), and the fact that when you call `apply` or `call` on `Foo[K]`, the compiler unhelpfully widens its type to a union of overloaded functions which is [unfortunately uncallable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#caveats).  My solution would look like this:

```
const invoke = <K extends keyof OnlyFunctions<Foo>>(
    method: K,
    ...args: Parameters<Foo[K]>
): ReturnType<Foo[K]> => {
    const fooMethod: { apply(f: Foo, args: Parameters<Foo[K]>): ReturnType<Foo[K]> } =
        foo[method];
    return fooMethod.apply(foo, args)
};
```

Here I've guided the compiler toward a more useful type for `foo[method]` by assigning it to an intermediate variable called `fooMethod`, whose `apply()` method is known to be of the right type.  This compiles and runs properly:

```
console.log(invoke("a", 1, 2)) // 4
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdiAYgVzgY2ASwPZygXigAoA6MgQwCcBzAZwC4pyEBtAXQEoCA+JhAbgCwAKBGhIUAPJwANiAA8AFQA0UAMq9CAbxFQ9UFgGkomPAGsIIbADMoito0VG2UCAA9gEOABNa6qAD8UMaMcBAAbhCUIgC+LBZWtvZCosLi0NJyKOhYuLRKmlAACphoZkqqmQoqsAjZGDhw3NwpIiKmnpTW5GjQiNjYUDrC+kyMRG4AjKHIALYARlGqbgBMMwtRXPi8cHOLlCmj8+MgjLTAlKbUW7znl3DUKTFtwmh5wFDWA4z9g9q6+nI4zc632y2mUF2G0oNyGUEoEGAyEoeDcUAA1FAphioJMoDFlAC9MdiKcoHcrrCtPDEci8CAcQAiECM-GE4TPV7vExwcLYCwEKDyYzuTw+PwJGxSWRIVANPLyX7NIhEqCzREAC2w3kYhnZozIJCodEYRSo5HVnXyv2c3BEHEYACVaSjFOAIIqBraeENVW84OdPgMALKa7WMankMBgOREaw-AaqY0MYrmy1Ra1ewxsbgOqDOpGu92e7DemIEVWjL6ly1a7xsQ76BGFvDV0PAOtG6Ox6tJmi0DixfhQF7+2jYGQQEgybDUIimPkWIiM8iM1STVQrDhcAD0O6gABYXkA)